# How to extract the text coordinates in an image using tess4j

Tags: image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to figure out how to get the coordinates and word rect in a text image after tess4j performs the OCR. i'm quite the beginner so can somebody please break it down for me? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tess4J's unit tests include examples for obtaining bounding boxes for recognized words. The code is similar to [Tess4J: How to use ResultIterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794551/tess4j-how-to-use-resultiterator/).

Comment: Thanks you very much. Can i, by any chance, get an entire example code? Just a very simple one. (And can i say, i am very much star struck by you Quan Nguyen.)

Comment: The unit tests can be found in the project's code repository: http://sourceforge.net/p/tess4j/code/181/tree/Tess4J_3/trunk/test/net/sourceforge/tess4j/

Comment: The test case testResultIterator represents a complete example for determining the bounding boxes. The code is rather straight forward -- you should be able to follow it.

Comment: I tried executing the tessiterator code and i witnessed the following error:

Comment: # Problematic frame:
# C  [libtesseract302.dll+0xf834]  tesseract::TessBaseAPI::Init+0x34
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows


I am using Eclipse to build my project. Is thee a patch that can fix the driver file which seems to be the problem here.

Comment: It's possible that your files are corrupted. Try download the [distribution](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tess4j/files/tess4j/1.1/) again.

Comment: Done. Still the same error. But the basic example code runs with no errors.

Comment: Not all of them. The testTessBaseAPIGetUTF8Text and the testResultIterator fail with the same error. The rest of the test cases in that particular class run without errors.

Comment: i think i know what the problem is. I have to implement the TessBaseAPI methods, dont i? The tessBaseAPIImpl class in the unit tests is left unimplememted.

Comment: The implementation of all the methods in the tessBaseAPI need to be done by me hence all the unit tests containing the handle for the TeessBaseAPI are failing.

Comment: How can i get the source code in the dll file? It would help in creating the wrapper if i had the c++ code to understand...

Answer (score 1):

I'm rather new to tess4j myself and I'd hate to disagree with @nguyenq, but here's how I did it

```
String imageUrl = "...";
File imageFile = new File(imageUrl);
Image image = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
BufferedImage bi = toBufferedImage(image);
ITesseract instance = new Tesseract();

for(Word word : instance.getWords(bi, ITessAPI.TessPageIteratorLevel.RIL_TEXTLINE)) {
  Rectangle rect = word.getBoundingBox();

  System.out.println(rect.getMinX()+","+rect.getMaxX()+","+rect.getMinY()+","+rect.getMaxY()
                    +": "+word.getText());
}
```

And here's my toBufferedImage method

```
public static BufferedImage toBufferedImage(Image img)
{
  if (img instanceof BufferedImage)
  {
      return (BufferedImage) img;
  }

  // Create a buffered image with transparency
  BufferedImage bimage = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

  // Draw the image on to the buffered image
  Graphics2D bGr = bimage.createGraphics();
  bGr.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
  bGr.dispose();

  // Return the buffered image
  return bimage;
}
```

[SO credit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605248/java-converting-image-to-bufferedimage)

**Edit** I should note that this is using tess4j v3.3.1. This new convenience API must have been added by @nguyenq after the initial question was posted