# tesseract how to find the blob

Tags: tesseract

I'd like to use tesseract-ocr making newspaper's page layout analysis, in order to find the blobs(titles, paragraphs) on iOS platform. I don't know how to achieve it and how to use the tesseract API.There are some mistakes:

```
        tesseract::PageIterator *pageIterator = tesseract->AnalyseLayout();
```

error : Member access into incomplete type 'tesseract::PageIterator'

```
        tesseract::PageIteratorLevel * level = pageIterator->level();
        int *left; int *top; int *right; int *bottom;
        pageIterator->BoundingBox(level,left,top,right,bottom);
```

error : Member access into incomplete type 'tesseract::PageIterator'

I need your advice. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The code is going to be similar to [Tess4J: How to use ResultIterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794551/tess4j-how-to-use-resultiterator), but at RIL_PARA or RIL_BLOCK level.